# Why is this code to reverse a word not working?

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++. I've written a small code to reverse a word. But it is not showing any output. Please explain.

```
void * reverse(char * arr)
{    
 int endindex;

 endindex=length(arr)-1;
 
 
 char * str;
 int i=0;

 while(endindex>0)
 {  
     str[i]=arr[endindex];
      i++;
      endindex--;
 }
 
 str[i++]=arr[endindex];
 str[i]='\0';
 cout<< str;
 
}
```

Comment: i've written function called "length" to know the length of string

Comment: `std::reverse(arr, arr + length(arr));`

Comment: `str` is an uninitialized `char *` so `str[i] = ...` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: As I can see from your code, you somewhere must have typed `using namespace std;`, but `std` has member called `reverse`, and your function is also called `reverse`. I would recommend not typing `using namespace std;` to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: I changed the function name,still it is not working

Comment: You could try C++. You wrote C.

Comment: is your length function is working properly?

Comment: Also note that `reverse` is declared to return a `void *` but has no `return` statement -- that's also undefined behaviour.

Comment: You swap every pair of characters twice. Debugging it would have made things clear for you. It's a crucial skill. One that is sadly underemphasized in beginner courses/tutorials.

Comment: [working code](https://ideone.com/W42gap) with errors fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Using C++ and the standard library, reversing a string is as simple as:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>  // std::reverse
#include <iostream>
#include <string>  // string class

int main() {
  std::string str{"Reverse me!"};
  std::reverse(str.begin(), str.end());
  std::cout << str << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
!em esreveR
```

As was pointed out, the code above doesn't really help you with your code. My intent was to illustrate that no, you're not really learning C++, but C, and not good C at that. The library `<cstring>` provides a function `strlen()`, for example, which calculates a C-string length for you. I take umbrage with beginner assignments that ask you to replicate library functions.

Since I feel that the comments under your question help you sufficiently with your code, here's my take a more C-like approach:

```cpp
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

/*
 * Function to reverse the characters of a C-string
 *
 * Return: None
 *
 * Parameters:
 *   str: The string to be reversed; is reversed in-place
 *
 * NOTES:
 *   - Normally, when passing a C-array, you should always pass
 *     the size along as well. Since this function caters
 *     exclusively to C-strings, I'll make an exception
 */
void reverse_c_string(char* str) {
  // My preference for the foor loop is minor, but
  // better contains the variables concerned with the loop
  for (int i = 0, endIdx = std::strlen(str) - 1; endIdx > i; ++i, --endIdx) {
    int tmp = str[i];
    str[i] = str[endIdx];
    str[endIdx] = tmp;
  }
}

int main() {
  char phrase[] = "Reverse me!";
  std::cout << phrase << '\n';
  reverse_c_string(phrase);
  std::cout << phrase << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
Reverse me!
!em esreveR
```

Comment: While technically correct, this does nothing to answer the original question asked.

Comment: I'll lead off by acknowledging and agreeing with your statement. My edit probably doesn't change your sentiment. But the approach of making the minimal amount of fixes to existing code is noble and is one I use when I think there is actual benefit in doing so. There are times where the code in question indicates large holes in learning. In this case, OP isn't really learning C++ at all. Even the C they are being taught is flawed. They're hobbling along with a broken leg and the minimal changes approach is only a crutch so they can hobble better.

Comment: Intro students need good foundational practices, because those early-learned bad practices like `using namespace std;` are very difficult to break. I've seen it first-hand. Some students would get the minimal changes approach, and others would be asked to re-think their solutions because they're not changing their thought process (which should be the real goal of any Intro to Programming course).